# A view to get children when parent is given

Tags: sql, oracle, view, hierarchical-data

I have a table with data of parent and child.

```
Parent | Child
---------------
  A      B
  B      C
  C      D
```

I want to get all the children form this table when I put where condition for parent.

ex -

```
select * from view where parent = 'A'
```

result should be B,C,D.

How do I write a view to get this output.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (parent, child) as
  2    (select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
  3     select 'B', 'C' from dual union all
  4     select 'C', 'D' from dual
  5    )
  6  select max(ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(child, '-'), '-')) result
  7  from test
  8  connect by prior child = parent
  9  start with parent = 'A';

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

B-C-D

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Listagg and Hierarchy clause

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2eda07/3)

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CHILD, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CHILD) FROM (
SELECT CHILD FROM TABLE1 START WITH PARENT = 'A' CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD = PARENT);
```